# How to obtain certificate of HTTPS binding my application is running under?

Tags: c#, wcf, ssl, wcf-data-services, x509certificate

I have an C# web application (WCF data service to be specific) which uses certificates (RSACryptoServiceProvider) to encrypt/decrypt some data. The application is running under website with HTTPS binding. Is there any way how to get private and public key of certificate configured in the HTTPS binding?

ps: Yes I know, the communication is encrypted by default, but the data I recieve/send comes from another source (not the client) and I need to decrypt/encrypt them manually.

Comment: Unless you are sure that certificate has the necessary key usage, you should avoid using it. You can easily access certificate store if your application pool identity has the permission. But to know which certificate is used for your web site, you need to use Microsoft.Web.Administration API.

Comment: I am searching for the certificate (by configured name) in the storage, now. It is acceptable, but I am looking for some easy solution. Something like 'SecurityContext.Current.Certificate' etc.

Comment: That's really something **only you need**. Client certificates are useful for ASP.NET/WCF app to learn the clients, but the server certificate is merely used for transportation security. There is no obvious need to expose it to ASP.NET/WCF.